# DateTime.Today Error

Tags: vb.net

In VS2010 for a VB.NET 4.0 project, the IDE puts a green line under the last line in the following code:

```
Dim cityLocal As DateTime
cityLocal = externalFunction()
cityLocal.Today()
```

The suggested code replace is to update 'cityLocal' with 'Date'. The reason is:
Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

But it does compile and does work correctly. Is this just a bug in the VS2010?

Comment: I doubt your current code does what you expect it to.  What do you want to do here?

Comment: It is performing exactly what I want it to-do, basically I just want the date with midnight returned. I'm just trying to figure out the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today is a shared member, thus should not (but can) be accessed through an instance of DateTime change your code to.

`DateTime.Today`

Although Visual Studio gives you suggestions to correct the "Error" it is infact a compiler warning, warning you that there is no need for an instance to access the shared member. You'll find that it is not listed as an error in the error list. Which is why it compiles correctly.

The Visual Basic language specification states

> 9.2.4 Shared Methods
>
> The Shared modifier indicates a method
>   is a shared method. A shared method
>   does not operate on a specific
>   instance of a type and may be invoked
>   directly from a type rather than
>   through a particular instance of a
>   type. It is valid, however, to use an
>   instance to qualify a shared method.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=01EEE123-F68C-4227-9274-97A13D7CB433:

More information on the warning can be found in the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6t76186.aspx

Comment: So should I create my own method that has the same behavior as the today method? What is the downside to using a static method in an instance?

Comment: @Josh. What are you expecting to see from `cityLocal.Today()`? I think you *may* want `cityLocal.Date`. `Date` is the date in `cityLocal` minus the time portion (or midnight to be technical). `DateTime.Today()` is **today's date**, regardless of any DateTime variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.Today` is a `static` (`Shared` in VB.NET) property. You are able to use it from an instance because the compiler knows to make the proper call, but it is not the expected usage pattern, which is both unnecessary and undesirable to use directly from an instance.

As a static variable, you should use `Date.Today` rather than `variable.Today`.

Answer (score 0):

Today is a shared/static member. Normally you would use `DateTime.Today` not your instance variable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx